# Defective laptops problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Among $10$ laptop computers, seven are good, the rest have defects. Unaware of this, a
customer buys $5$ laptops.

a) What is the probability of exactly $2$ defective ones among them (event A)?

b) Knowing that at least $2$ purchased laptops are defective, what is the probability that exactly
$2$ are defective (event B)?

Can somebody give me some ideas,please? I can't figure out what probabilistic model to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a)

$$\mathbb{P}[A]=\frac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{7}{3}}{\binom{10}{5}}=\frac{5}{12}$$

b)

$$\mathbb{P}[B]=\frac{\frac{5}{12}}{1-\frac{\binom{3}{0}\binom{7}{5}}{\binom{10}{5}}-\frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{7}{4}}{\binom{10}{5}}}=\frac{\frac{5}{12}}{1-\frac{1}{12}-\frac{5}{12}}=\frac{5}{12-1-5}=\frac{5}{6}$$

Comment: But I am curious how did you get that formula

Comment: @poiuyt : It's the hypergeometric law